# How can I read below Json column stored in SQL Server using openjson?

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, open-json, sql-server-json

```
Declare @ResponseText nvarchar(4000)

set @responseText ='{
    "submissions": [
        {
        "xml_id":"id_x5d94851726b470.68571510",
        "fields": [ 
            {"fieldvalue":"customerEmail@xyzdomain.com","fieldid":"57282490"},
            {"fieldvalue":"123","fieldid":"57282423"},
            {"fieldvalue":"12345-678900","fieldid":"57282500"}, 
            {"fieldvalue":"Test Message here ","fieldid":"57282564"}
         ]
         }
    ]
 }'

 SELECT  *
 FROM OPENJSON (@ResponseText, '$.submissions') WITH (
    ID NVARCHAR(100) '$.xml_id',
    $.fields.field NVARCHAR(100) ...
 )
```

etc rest of all the record? I got "NULL" for the rest fields under fields array

Comment: Can you add the desired results to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
Declare @ResponseText nvarchar(4000)

set @responseText ='{
    "submissions": [
        {
        "xml_id":"id_x5d94851726b470.68571510",
        "fields": [ 
            {"fieldvalue":"customerEmail@xyzdomain.com","fieldid":"57282490"},
            {"fieldvalue":"123","fieldid":"57282423"},
            {"fieldvalue":"12345-678900","fieldid":"57282500"}, 
            {"fieldvalue":"Test Message here ","fieldid":"57282564"}
         ]
         }
    ]
 }'
```

--The query

```
 SELECT A.ID
       ,B.*
 FROM OPENJSON (@ResponseText, '$.submissions') 
      WITH (ID NVARCHAR(100) '$.xml_id'
           ,fields NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
 OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(a.fields)
             WITH(fieldvalue NVARCHAR(150)
                 ,fieldid BIGINT) B;
```

The result

```
ID                          fieldvalue                  fieldid
id_x5d94851726b470.68571510 customerEmail@xyzdomain.com 57282490
id_x5d94851726b470.68571510 123                         57282423
id_x5d94851726b470.68571510 12345-678900                57282500
id_x5d94851726b470.68571510 Test Message here           57282564
```

The idea in short:

You started correctly using the `WITH`-clause to read the `xml_id`. The property `fields` is nothing else than another element on the same level. But we return it `AS JSON`. This will allow to add another `APPLY OPENJSON()`, pass in the fragment we got from `$.fields` and use another `WITH`-clause to get the two properties of the objects within the array.

Comment: Thank you Shnugo for correct answer , it worked out by you kind support and helpful example and explanations as well.  I am greatly appreciated .